# Из чего состоит foreach?

Tags: c#, foreach

Проходил собеседование на .NET разработчика. Дали задачу, в которой нужно было сказать, что выведет в последней строке (не суть). Суть в том, что в коде присутствовал цикл foreach, который перебирал элементы коллекций. Когда я начал решать задачу, последовал вопрос "А Вы знаете из чего состоит foreach?". Ответить я не смог, и после собеседования начал искать ответ на вопрос, но не нашел.

Вопрос: Из каких конструкций состоит foreach?

Comment: `while`? Можете посмотреть например [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-foreach-statement) (строка `затем расширяется до:`).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ооо, спасибо большое. Как раз то, что искал.

Comment: Сделайте ответ тогда (не в вопросе, а ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Вот это:

```
foreach (V v in x) embedded_statement
```

тоже самое, что и это:

```
{
    E e = ((C)(x)).GetEnumerator();
    try {
        while (e.MoveNext()) {
            V v = (V)(T)e.Current;
            embedded_statement
        }
    }
    finally {
        ... // Dispose e
    }
}
```

[Источник](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-foreach-statement)